# Problema em implementar a edição em Angular

Tags: angular

Observem a imagem a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em editar além de ser direcionado para a página de edição era para carregar o formulário, porém o formulário não está sendo carregado, e veja como está.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Era para ficar assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o que está acontecendo de errado, preciso de ajuda.

Esse é o método na classe de serviços.

```
 editEvento(token, id, evento){
      let params = JSON.stringify(evento);
      let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': token
      });

      return this._http.put(this.url+'evento/'+id, params, {headers: headers})
               .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Esse é minha classe do componente.

```
import { desaparecer } from './../../animation';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';

import { Evento } from './../../models/evento';
import { UploadService } from './../../core/upload.service';
import { EventoService } from './../../core/evento.service';
import { UserService } from './../../core/user.service';
import { Component, DoCheck, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  public title: string;
  public evento: Evento;
  public identity;
  public token;
  public url: string;
  public status;
  public is_edit;

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _eventoService: EventoService,
    private _uploadService: UploadService
  ) {
      this.is_edit = true;
      this.title = 'Atualizar Evento';
      this.evento = new Evento('','','',2018,'', '');
      this.identity = this._userService.getIdentity();
      this.token = this._userService.getToken();
      this.url = environment.url;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvento();
  }


  getEvento() {
    this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];

      this._eventoService.getEvento(id).subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response.evento) {
            this._router.navigate(['/home']);
          } else {
            this.evento = response.evento;
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
          this._router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
      );

    });
  }


  onSubmit(){
    var id = this.evento._id;
    this._eventoService.editEvento(this.token, id, this.evento).subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response.evento) {
            this.status = 'error';
          } else {
            this.status = 'success';
            this.evento = response.evento;

            // Subir imagen do evento
            if (!this.filesToUpload) {
            this._router.navigate(['/evento', this.evento._id ]);
            } else {
            // Subida de la imagen
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(this.url+'upload-image-evento/'+ this.evento._id, [], this.filesToUpload, this.token, 'image')
                .then((result: any) => {
                    this.evento.image = result.image;
                    this._router.navigate(['/evento', this.evento._id ]);
                  });
              }
            }
      },
      error => {
        var errorMessage = <any>error;

        if(errorMessage != null){
          this.status = 'error';
        }
      }
      );
    }

  public filesToUpload: Array<File>;
    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
      this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    }




}
```

E [clique aqui](https://github.com/wladyband/epui/blob/master/src/app/admin/edit/edit.component.ts) para ter acesso ao meu repositório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a imagem fornecida, parece que seu html (edit.component.html) está com o html padrão que o angular criou.

Comment: Exatamente, o autor da pergunta esqueceu de escrever o código HTML da página.

Comment: @Arnaldo R. Portela isso já sabia, não tinha como colocar todo o código do projeto.
eu não esqueci de colocar a pagina padrão do edit é que ao clicar no botão editar e para ele carregar a pagina de salvar como tivesse editando. O projeto do curso funciona perfeitamente, mas o meu não funciona, deve ser uma bolbagem.

Comment: eu coloquei o link do repositório na minha postagem.

Comment: Então, no repositório, seu html está com o conteúdo padrão, não tem o html da página em questão